# Speeding up page loading on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, load, wordpress-theming

I have a site set up on Wordpress that is extremely slow to load.

At first I just blamed the slideshow on the homepage, but now I look closer I can see even the basic pages are slow to load: http://www.marcusmcshane.com/bio/

Can anyone share some tips on speeding this up?

I admit I created the theme when I didn't know much about WP, so it may be excessively bulky. It is hosted with GoDaddy. It uses the latest version of WP and of the following plugins: AStickyPostOrderER, Category Posts Widget, Nivo Slider WordPress Plugin, W3 Total Cache, Widget Logic

Thanks!

Comment: In a tracert I get a timeout consistently at hope 4 (for me). Also, server is hosted in singapore and response time is pretty slow from here in eastern us.

Comment: Thanks @mrtsherman - the site is for a New Zealand designer so perhaps Singapore hosting isn't as bad for them...

Comment: If you do a `tracert www.marcusmcshane.com` do you also get the timeout? If this is a general routing issue that is going to slow things down because an alternate path will need to be used.

Comment: Yes it times out for me too... From the second line!  But I have to admit I am only now reading up on what this means. To use an alternative path, do I contact the GoDaddy for that? Sorry for my naiveté...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GoDaddy is well known as a crappy, overloaded host. No amount of caching or use of a CDN, etc., will help with over-shared servers and network latency. Best to find another host. http://wordpress.org/hosting/

Comment: Just what I was afraid of hearing! But thanks, will certainly look into a new host.

Comment: Yes, you can try calling your ISP and your host and complain about bad routing. They will then point their fingers at each other and run away. There is lots of good, inexpensive hosts out there. Find one!

Comment: Thank you both. I can see that the caching plugin has had no effect on the loading speed, so I guess the only real answer is to change host.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely don't use Godaddy.  In hosting, you get what you pay for.  I would suggest going with Mediatemple's Grid service account. At 20/month, you can't really beat it. It allows you to create multiple Wordpress sites as well and they have an optional CDN if you want to pay for it (assuming your site is very high traffic it makes sense). I host about 20 sites on my GS account right now.

I use a combination of three systems to manage all of my client sites.  Dynadot for domains, Google Apps free (see google.com/a/) for web and desktop email, and Mediatemple for web hosting.  Client's have never complained once that their site was slow to load.

In my experience it's always better to separate web hosting, domain hosting, and email hosting.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain techniques used to optimize the loading time for your WordPress Site. Such as:

- Minimizing http requests
- Combine external files
- Minify css and javascript
- Optimize images

Or you can get a plugin for WordPress that does all that for you. There is one I know that does all of this really well [JCH Optimize](https://www.jch-optimize.net). And support for it is really good. They are others but i like this one the best as it has really easy to use configuration options.